# How to I identify the row the user selects in my table?

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am producing a set of users from my `DB` in an `HTML table` using a `while loop`. The idea is that the user will select the 'add user' button and the a `query` is run to add that row to the relevant project. However I cannot work out how to tell the query which row of data to add. Any suggestions?

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" >
            <p><strong>Search Results:</strong></p>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><strong>First Name</strong></td>
              <td><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
              <td><strong>Job Role</strong></td>
              <td><strong>Skill(s)</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['search'])){

                        if(@mysqli_num_rows($search_query)!=0){
                            do{ 
                            ?>
<tr>
              <td>
              <form action="AddUserToProject.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($Project); ?>" method="post" id="addform">
                    <input type="submit" name="adduser" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($search_rs['UserID']); ?>"/>
              </form>
              </td>
              <td><?php echo $search_rs['Fname']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $search_rs['Lname']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $search_rs['JobRole']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $search_rs['Description']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php   

            } while ($search_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));
                          } else {
                                echo "No results found";
                            }}

            if(isset($_POST['adduser']))
            {
                    $AddUserID = $search_rs['UserID'];
                    $AddProjectID = $Project;

                    $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO userprojects 
                                    (UserID, ProjectID) 
                                    VALUES  
                                    ('$AddUserID', '$AddProjectID')") 
                                    or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
                            } 
                        ?>
            </table>
```

Search = my search field above.

Comment: Maybe put the table in a form then for each row add an checkbox or radiobutton and as a value set the row id or user id and let that process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press the 'adduser' button, it posts the form data. The user_id appears to be stored as the value of the 'adduser' button. Therefore:

Change:

```
$AddUserID = $search_rs['UserID'];
```

To:

```
$AddUserID = $_POST['adduser'];
```

Don't forget to clean your post data for security.

Comment: Hmm just noticed something. It is adding the row twice, any ideas why its doing this?